# How I can get data from table laravel model

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

I got two tables (Models),
tags with id and name and
post_tag with post_id and tag_id.

How I can get from table tags name but with table post_tag post_id.

Comment: where is your code that's you've already tired ?

Answer (score 0):

Look, you haven't given any code sample. But from your question, I guess that you've two model named, `Tag` & `Post`

So, your post_tag became the pivot table right. And it is a many-to-many relation.

In your `Tag` model build relation like,

```
public function postTag()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_tag', 'tag_id', 'post_id');
    }
```

In same way, in your `Post` model add a relation like

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
    }
```

Now, your pivot relation is ready. At the time off attaching tags with `Post`, use `$post->tags()->attach(Tag::find($tag)); // $post = new Post(); $tag is tag_id`

To retrieve all post with associated tags, call

`Post::with('tags')->get();`

Similarly, to get tags associated with post

`Tag::with('postTag')->get();`

Head to laravel official website for many-to-many relations documentation
[laravel One To Many Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)